# Remote Desktop Connection Manager won't save domain\username when remote computer doesn't allow saved credentials

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-connection

I have several remote desktop servers that do not allow saved credentials, however, I would like to be able to save the domain\username so I only have to type the password to connect to the server. I've tried saving the domain and username without a password, and that also doesn't seem to help. On my previous computer, I did not have this issue, it is only since upgrading to a newer windows 10 laptop.

Comment: you may want to look for an alternative client to RDCMan, with password vault capabilities. I believe there are several out there.

Comment: Did you save RDP credentials with Admin credentials on the prior mschine?

Comment: Try using mRemoteNG software (free). It allows you to create connection files with domain/user and also passwords. You can create an entire database of remote connections and export them to xml form for any other users in your department as well. It supports VNC, RDP and SSH. https://mremoteng.org/